# D3 path transition direction

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I need some help with my following D3 line chart, where x is a time domain and y is linear scale value, currently [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/realnumber/3h4SW/2/), the transition of path occurs from right to left, but I want it to happen as left to right instead.

```
var data = [{"closedate":"2013-12-07T08:00:00.000Z","amount":60000}];

//Set Canvas Area properites
    var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 100},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    //X value transformation function - transforms close date into chart x position of canvas
    var x = d3.time.scale()
              .range([0, width])
              .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.closedate); }));

    //Y Value transformation function - transforms amount into y position of canvas
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
              .range([height, 0])
              .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.amount; }));

    //X Axis Function
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        //.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%m/%y'))
        .ticks(6)
        .orient("bottom");

    //Y Axis Function
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(6).orient("left");

    //Line Function to draw SVG Line
    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("cardinal")
        .x(function(d) { return x(new Date(d.closedate)); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.amount); });

    //Create SVG canvas area with height and width properites
    var svg = d3.select("#d3linechartid").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //console.log("data = "+JSON.stringify(data));

    //Draw XAxis
    svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
          .append("text")
          .attr("x", width )
          .attr("y", "50")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text("Close Date");

    //Draw YAxis
    svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text("Sales Amount ($)");

    //Draw SVG Path
    var path = svg.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("d", line)
          .style('fill', 'none')
          .style('stroke', 'steelblue')
          .attr("stroke-width", "2");


    //Do Transistion of Path
    var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
    path
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength+","+totalLength)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .ease("linear-in-out")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the input data in ascending order, like so:

`data.sort(function(a, b){ return d3.ascending(a.closedate, b.closedate); });`